# Java error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, linux, solr

I'm trying to to run my freshly installed apache solr on my server (CENTOS 5.2 x86_64) and I get the followoing error messages:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: start/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: start.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: start.jar.  Program will exit.
```

This is the commend I ran: `java start.jar`

As far as I'm aware everything is installed correctly.

Any ideas?

Thanks
C

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run it with `java -jar`, not `java`:

```
java -jar start.jar
```

The `java` command is used for running .class files, while the `java -jar` command actually executes the code in the jar properly, using the manifest file to interpret the jar's contents.